# Where are the submit and reset event types specified?

Tags: html, dom, dom-events

The submit and reset event types are not specified in the DOM 3 Events standard. This is a [quote from that standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#changes-drafts):

> The change, submit, and reset events
> were removed, since they were specific
> to HTML forms, and are specified in
> HTML5.

However, I am unable to find their specifications in the [HTML5 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

Can you help me find them? You can load the [single-page version of HTML5 here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html) and then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're in the [list of event types that must be supported on HTML elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers-on-elements-document-objects-and-window-objects) but with no details; just their names.  Are you looking for more than that?

Another source: the WHATWG group is developing what they call an ev[olving HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/index.html#contents); they no longer talk about HTML5 as such, but admit that what they are working on is HTML 5.  They have more details about the [submit](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#concept-form-submit) and [reset](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#concept-form-reset) events.

Comment: Yes, of course. Event type specifications in the HTML5 standard [look like so](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#event-media-loadstart).

Comment: Those are media events; the standard doesn't include details specs for a number of element events.  But see the additional links I added to my answer.

Comment: That is it, you found it. `:)` Note that this exact chapter (4.10.22.3) also exists in the HTML5 standard that I referenced in my question. [See here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm).

Comment: Hey, look at that.  Seems like the WHATWG site is doing better on Google than the W3C site.  :)